# Failing to install IdP configuration with helm in Openshift 4

Tags: openshift

I'm trying to apply htpasswd IdP configuration with oc apply commands which is working, but when I'm using configuration with helm it is failing to install with following error,

Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: rendered manifests contain a resource that already exists. Unable to continue with install: OAuth "cluster" in namespace "" exists and cannot be imported into the current release:

Can someone help ?

Regards
Mallikharjuna Rao Polisetty

Answer (score 0):

This is a helm issue. The helm chart you're using is trying to place an resource of type `oauth` named `cluster` onto your OpenShift cluster, which already exists (supposedly because you created it by hand).
Clean up the existing `oauth` and try again.